# How do I get whole html from Apify Cheerio crawler?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, web-crawler, apify

I want to get the whole html not just text.

```
Apify.main(async () => {


const requestQueue = await Apify.openRequestQueue();
await requestQueue.addRequest({ 
    url: //adress,
    uniqueKey: makeid(100)
```

});

```
const handlePageFunction = async ({ request, $ }) => {
    var content_to = $('.class')

    
};

// Set up the crawler, passing a single options object as an argument.
const crawler = new Apify.CheerioCrawler({
    requestQueue,
    handlePageFunction,
});

await crawler.run();
```

});

When I try this the crawler returns complex object. I know I can extract the text from the content_to variable using .text() but I need the whole html with tags like . What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly - you could just use `.html()` instead of `.text()`. This way you will get inner html instead of inner text of the element.

Another thing to mention - you could also put `body` to `handlePageFunction` arg object:
`const handlePageFunction = async ({ request, body, $ }) => {`

`body` would have the whole raw html of the page.